# Php, MySql, single query with two counts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I need to perform two different counts in one single query.

```
First Query: count number of transactions from today 30 days back.
Second Query: count number of transactions from last 60 until last 30 days.
```

I have first query working fine as:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS sales 
FROM
  transactions 
WHERE DATE(created) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
  AND STATUS = 1;
```

How can I incorporate the second query into the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` and `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(created) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS c1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(created) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS c2
FROM transactions 
WHERE DATE(created) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
  AND STATUS = 1;
```

or `UNION`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS sales 
FROM transactions 
WHERE DATE(created) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
  AND STATUS = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM transactions 
WHERE DATE(created) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
  AND DATE(created) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
  AND STATUS = 1
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfect. I have not tested Union, but using case is lot cleaner.